# proof of propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$((A \land (A \rightarrow B))  \rightarrow B$

$((A \land (A \rightarrow B))$ is premise
and $B$ is goal

$((A \land (\neg A \lor B))$

$(((A \land \neg A)  \lor ( A \land B))$

How to prove this is true? Whether using contradiction or anything else?

Comment: We have $A$ and $A\rightarrow B$.  Now assume $\neg B$ from which $\neg A$ follows. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
((A \land (A \rightarrow B))  \rightarrow B &\equiv (( A \land (\neg A \lor B))  \rightarrow B\\
&\equiv (( A \land \neg A) \lor (A \land B))  \rightarrow B\\
&\equiv (F \lor (A \land B))  \rightarrow B\\
&\equiv (A \land B)  \rightarrow B\\
&\equiv \neg(A \land B)  \lor B\\
&\equiv (\neg A \lor \neg B) \lor B\\
&\equiv \neg A \lor (\neg B \lor B)\\
&\equiv \neg A \lor T\\
&\equiv T\\
\end{align}

As @Michael Hoppe's comment, we can use the contradiction to prove that is true.

Assuming $\neg B$. Given $A\land (A\to B)$, which we can conclude is $\neg A$. This is contradiction. So, the propositional logic $(A\land (A\to B))\to B$ is true.

Comment: Why downvote? I think this is true answer. To answer this question we can prove using laws of logic or truth table.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: replace $A \to B$ with its equivalent: $B \lor \lnot A$ .